# League of Legends, Miss Fortune's ultimate is glitching

Tags: league-of-legends

**Background**

I am playing Miss Fortune in League of Legends, and her ultimate is that she stands still in a spot and sends out 17 waves of bullets in a cone in front of her, dealing massive damage.

**Miss Fortune's ultimate examples**
[1]:

**Problem**

The issue is that often when I activate the ultimate, the character still does the animation and the sound still happens, but no bullets come out and no damage is dealt. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I would guess you got a file that is broken in your install. Have you checked for 'verify integrity of game files'? Its in the client's options. The no damage part is really weird tho, since that is calculated server side. Could you post a replay of the game where it happens? You might have got a glitch that happened once in LCS, where there was a minion in the face of the MF and it just absorbed the whole damage.

Comment: @Fredy31 this is not possable as it's an area of effect damage, so it pass thought targets

Comment: Never underestimate Riot's spagetti code lol. I'll try to find the replay for you.

Comment: does this look like what you are getting? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzcfQW2bRWg

Comment: @Fredy31 OMG were did you find that yes it's like that

Comment: Then, i'm sorry, but you are in Rito Jank, But that bug is not supposed to happen very often. I play MF pretty often and can't tell it has ever happened to me.

Comment: @Fredy31 thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miss Fortune's ult is known to do this sometimes, unfortunately as of right now there is no fix to this bug.